# ¿Los media query se situan al final del archivo css o se hace un media query por elemento a modificar?

Tags: html, css

Hola gente estoy haciendo un curso y me surgio una duda, yo siempre me acostumbre a usar los media query al final del archivo css modificando lo necesario para adaptarlo a las diferentes resoluciones, pero he visto que hay personas que en vez de realizar un media query global con todos sus elementos, hacen un media query por elemento ej

```
h1{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

@media (min-width:768px){
    h1{
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
}



p{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

@media (min-width:768px){
    p{
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
}
```

entiendo que esto permite quizas tener una mejor organizacion del codigo y evitar scrollear de arriba a abajo pero conlleva a que hacer un media query por cada elemento a modificar, ustedes que hacen? cual es la "mejor" practica? desde ya gracias

Comment: Salvo que alguien juicioso llegue acá con una buena respuesta, creería que esto es más de _coding standards_, estándares de condificación de un proyecto. Si todos en el proyecto acuerdan que van a codificar de X forma, lo importante es ser consistentes para poderlo mantener.

Comment: gracias alfa por contestar

Comment: El css se implementa en orden de arriba hacia abajo y las reglas repetidas se sobrescriben. Por lo que colocar media query entre medio da un pequeño riesgo de pisar las reglas impuestas en ese media query. Esto me ha pasado cuando me toca modificar proyectos antiguos (de esos que uno ya ni recuerda que pensaba en ese momento), por eso yo prefiero dejarlos siempre abajo. Incluso en ficheros distintos (cuando lo amerita)

Comment: gracias yussef, tu respuesta es util

Comment: Independientemente  de lo que te digan, algo que siempre será cierto es que cuando haces una web intentas hacerla tan rápida como sea posible, forma de hacerla rápida es escribir tan poco código como sea posible, meter todo en un solo media query te permite ahorrarte muchas líneas de código y en programación web donde la velocidad de carga de la web es importante el escribir poco código y de forma optimizada debe ser prioridad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque tu hoja de estilos es válida te genera innecesariamente doble carga para actualizar cualquier modificación. Aprovechando que todo lo que quieras que aplique al breakpoint definido por 768px puedes ponerlo envuelto en el mismo media query, ese camino te hará la vida más fácil.

```
h1{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

p{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}   

@media (min-width:768px){
    h1{
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
    p{
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
}
```

Tanto mi sugerencia como la que tienes en tu pregunta son equivalentes e intercambiables, pero de todos los selectores soportados en la especificación CSS versiones 1 a la X, es importante importante entender que -entre dos reglas que se contradigan- **se prioriza por especificidad**. Esto se vuelve muy importante a medida que tu aplicación incorpora librerías externas y frameworks que vienen con sus propios estilos, los cuales sólo podrás "pisar" valiéndote de reglas más específicas que las de éstos.

En caso de "empate" en su especificidad, tiene prioridad la regla de estilo que aparece en último lugar. Y llegados a este punto, es preciso señalar que **[los media query no tienen efecto en la especificidad](https://css-tricks.com/how-much-specificity-do-rules-have-like-keyframes-and-media/)**, lo que significa que debes ponerlas después de la regla que quieres modificar, pues en caso contrario no tendrán efecto.

---

Si alguien quiere informarse más sobre el tema, puede mirar [Spefishity](https://specifishity.com/), que tiene una infografía bien ingeniosa. Por mi parte, y haciendo mi mejor esfuerzo por explicarlos en orden de importancia, dejo un paupérrimo resumen:

1. Especificidad de tipo (que es simplemente el nombre del tag), bonus para descendencia (`ul li`) extra bonus para descendencia directa (`ul > li`), relación de hermandad general (`thead ~ tbody`)  , extra bonus para hermandad adyacente (`thead + tbody`). En el siguiente caso el párrafo tiene tamaño 1rem, color rojo:

   ```
   div p {
     font-size: 1rem;
     color: blue;
   }
   div > p {
     color:red;
   }
   /* todas sus reglas están redefinidas con más prioridad */
   p {
     color: green;
     font-size: 2.5rem;
   }
   ```
2. Especificidad de clases y seudoclases, bonus para clases anidadas

   ```
   /* más específico que el último, pero menos que el siguiente */
   p.titulo {
     font-size: 1rem;
   }
   p.titulo:hover {
     font-size: 1.5rem;
   }
   p {
     font-size: 2.5rem;
   }
   ```

(nótese qué elegante es el hecho que, dado un selector, de cualquier especificidad, al darle estilo a la seudoclase `:hover` siempre nos queda un selector más específico que su homólogo sin seudoclase)

3. Especificidad de atributos

   ```
   /* más específico que el siguiente */
   p[name="párrafo"] {
     font-size: 1rem;
   }

   p {
     font-size: 2.5rem;
   }
   ```
4. Especificidad de id

   ```
   /* más específico que el siguiente */
   p#identificador {
     font-size: 1rem;
   }

   p {
     font-size: 2.5rem;
   }
   ```

La concurrencia de más de uno de estos criterios va sumando especificidad, pero, el modificador `!important` se impone a los demás, por específicos que sean

```
   p#identificador.titulo[name="parrafo"] {
     font-size: 1rem;
   }

   /* le gana a todos */
   p {
     font-size: 2.5rem !important;
   }
```

Como es difícil imaginarse qué estilo gana cuando dos reglas cuentan con varios criterios de prioridad, te hice una grilla donde las puse a competir.

```css
li {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 2em;
  width: 22vw;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: white;
  list-style: none;
  --texto: 'li';
}

li::before {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  width: 22vw;
  height: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(0, 0.5rem);
  content: var(--texto);
}

ul.grid {
  gap: 3px;
  height: 6rem;
  padding: 0;
}

.derecha {
  --texto: '.derecha';
}

.izquierda {
  --texto: '.izquierda';
}

.derecha:hover {
  --texto: '.derecha:hover';
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 2fr);
}

div li[name="caja6"] {
  --texto: 'div li[name="caja6"]';
}

div li[name="caja7"] {
  --texto: 'div li[name="caja7"]';
}

li {
  --texto: 'div ul li';
}

ul>li:nth-child(4n+2) {
  --texto: 'col 2';
}

li:nth-child(n+9) {
  --texto: 'fila 3';
}

ul>li:nth-child(6) {
  --texto: 'ul > li:nth-child(6)';
}

#caja5 {
  --texto: '#caja5';
}

li:nth-child(7n)+li {
  --texto: 'li:nth-child(7n) + li';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="grid">
    <li class="izquierda"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="derecha"></li>

    <li class="izquierda" id="caja5"></li>
    <li name="caja6"></li>
    <li name="caja7"></li>
    <li></li>

    <li class="izquierda"></li>
    <li id="noveno"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Para no confundir al lector: el uso de `--texto: 'bla bla';`   es simplemente definir una variable. En el seudoselector `::before` estoy diciendo `content: var(--texto);` con lo cual el valor de `--texto` se mostrará en ese seudoelemento. El ejemplo tiene múltiples selectores que afectan a los mismos elementos y se contradicen a la hora de definir la variable, así que lo que se ve en cada caja de la grilla representa el selector que finalmente se impuso. Iba a hacerlo con colores, pero me pareció más explícito mostrarlo con texto.

Podrán ver que el selector más básico `li` sólo es tomado en cuenta en ausencia de otros selectores. De ahí en adelante, los demás compiten con múltiples criterios.

Comment: muchas gracias ffflabs muy completo, se agradece